# Tkinter - Using bind to resize frame dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI front-end to display some data using python tkinter.

I have a Frame which in-turn has other widgets like, button and list-box etc.
I am trying to dynamically increase/decrease the frame whenever the cursor is placed on borders of frame just like we do on usual windows from user end.

[image]

I have gone through the binding functions for the same.
but looks like I am missing on something.

```
  def left_click(event):
      tkinter.Label(Frame1, text = "Left Click!").pack()



  self.Frame1 = Frame(top)        
  self.Frame1.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.152, relheight=0.678 , relwidth=0.98)
  self.Frame1.configure(relief=GROOVE)
  self.Frame1.configure(borderwidth="10")
  self.Frame1.configure(relief=GROOVE)
  self.Frame1.configure(background="#D1C8E6")
  self.Frame1.configure(width=900)
  self.Frame1.configure(highlightthickness="4")
  self.Frame1.bind("<Button-1>", left_click)
```

I am new to python tk inter.

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt at all to do the frame resizing that you say is your goal, so it's hard to tell exactly what you need help with.

Comment: Why do you think you are missing something? What is the program doing that is different than what you expect?

Comment: Bryan Oakley I was not able to figure out the correct bind functions. Could you please refer me with some links or documentation for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the following mouse events to perform frame resize:

- `<ButtonPress-1>` (mouse left button pressed) to determine whether resize should be started based on mouse position
- `<ButtonRelease-1>` (mouse left button released) to stop resize
- `<Motion>` (mouse moving within frame) to perform resize if resize is started by mouse pressed

Below is a sample code:

```
from tkinter import *

HORIZONTAL = 1
VERTICAL   = 2

class App:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.Frame1 = Frame(top, bd=5, relief='raised', width=100, height=100)
        self.Frame1.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.Frame1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_resize)
        self.Frame1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_resize)
        self.Frame1.bind("<Motion>", self.resize_frame)
        self.resize_mode = 0
        self.cursor = ''

    def check_resize_mode(self, x, y):
        width, height = self.Frame1.cget('width'), self.Frame1.cget('height')
        mode = 0
        if x > width-10: mode |= HORIZONTAL    
        if y > height-10: mode |= VERTICAL
        return mode

    def start_resize(self, event):
        self.resize_mode = self.check_resize_mode(event.x, event.y)

    def resize_frame(self, event):
        if self.resize_mode:
            if self.resize_mode & HORIZONTAL:
                self.Frame1.config(width=event.x)
            if self.resize_mode & VERTICAL:
                self.Frame1.config(height=event.y)
        else:
            cursor = 'size' if self.check_resize_mode(event.x, event.y) else ''
            if cursor != self.cursor:
                self.Frame1.config(cursor=cursor)
                self.cursor = cursor

    def stop_resize(self, event):
        self.resize_mode = 0

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+400+50")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: acw1668 Thank you so much. just perfect.

Comment: the sample is awesome !

Comment: @acw1668 Great answer. If you want to add some finishing touches you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194808/11106801). More specifically the `change_cursor_resizing` method. It has the cursor names for Linux and Windows.