# Tkinter check if window is visible

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to check if the root is visible (at least part of it is on the screen). I tried `<tk.Tk>.winfo_viewable()` and `<tk.Tk>.ismapped()` but both of them return `True` even if the window is fully hidden by another window. Checking if the window isn't focused wouldn't solve my problem.

I need it because I am working on improving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194808/11106801) that uses `<tk.Tk>.overrideredirect(True)` to remove the title bar. The problem is that I can't `Alt-Tab` to the window so I want to call `<tk.Tk>.overrideredirect(False)` each time the window isn't (at least partially) visible.

Comment: There was an idea of tkinter that, at least on windows, doesn't work. It's called by `winfo_visualsavailable` If it's not working you could go for alternative solutions like `topmost`. Or you go to pin your costum window on the taskbar, but this would be a system specific solution.

Comment: @Atlas435 nvm I figured it out a few days ago. I will post a solution in a few days. If anyone wants an answer right now look at [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/Bismuth-184/commit/46c06e8a51d788e546a4b1d17a733819f77b8ae5). Basically I create a dummy window that has `"1x1"` geometry and detect if the user focuses the dummy window.