# How to change the colour of tkinter window header without removing it from the taskbar?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, header, window

I'm creating a GUI in tkinter and I'm trying to customize the window header so I can change the colour.

I've used:

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

to get rid of the header, then rebuilt the function of moving the tab with:

```
def move_window(event):
    x, y = root.winfo_pointerxy()
    root.geometry(f"+{x-650}+{y}")

title_bar = tk.Frame(root, bg=pallete["pallete1"], bd=0,height=22)
title_bar.config(highlightthickness=2, highlightcolor= pallete["pallete3"])
title_bar.pack(fill="x")
title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
```

Only this is, that when I `overrideredirect` to get rid of the window header, the program disappears in the taskbar, so you can't find it.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to get around this or to change the window header without having to remove it and rebuild a new one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the title bar in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836000/can-i-change-the-title-bar-in-tkinter)

Comment: @nbk no, that's where I originally looked and used some of their code but still doesn't work

Comment: so you look for dragging win when you overrideriderct? or you need that icon if you minsize your app? for override here ist the perfect answer from TheLizzard = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968676/how-to-get-a-better-window-postion-if-i-click-on-an-overrideredirectted-window. It doesn't come clear to me what exactly you mean. also there is an option `iconify` you can use it with override

Comment: the accepted answer changes the color of the title bar to what your enter i tried it with green instead of white, , so can you explain what doesn't woirk with that answer?

Comment: @nbk that accepted answer lets you move and close the screen, I'm looking to be able to minimize then open it up again from the taskbar. 
root.overrideredirect(True) doesn't show the program in the taskbar.

Comment: @JoeMo thank you, this seems to help. I'm able to minimize by setting root.overrideredirect to False, but when I open the program, the window header now appears back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   
 def minsize():                    # minsize func() for your button
        root.overrideredirect(0)   # minsize window and iconify
        root.iconify()

def showwindow(event):
        root.overrideredirect(1)
        root.iconify()
```

bind this to your heading bar with `map`

```
your_widdgget.bind("<Map>", lambda event: showindow(event)) # in this case i don't know why lambda but it still works for me
```

Comment: saviour 
works now
I still had to adjust some things to fit my program but thanks so much!

Comment: if you have this `TclError`you can `except TclError`: pass ... I don't found a better solution. Maybe someone else knows how to handle it better.

Comment: What is `'Map'` here? It is `'<Map>'`. You don't need `lambda`.

Comment: i posted `<Map>` don*t know why `Map`