# Incorrect Formatting in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
color1 = '#031629'
color2 = '#1C1C1C'

root = Tk()
root.title('Everything BASE 1.0.0')
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.configure(bg = color1)
def minim():
    root.wm_state("iconic")

exit_button = Button(root, bg = color1, fg ='White', text = " X ", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.grid(row=0, column=0,)
min_button = Button(root, bg = color1, fg = 'White', text = ' - ', command = minim)
min_button.grid(row=0, column=1,)


frame = Frame(root, bg = color2, height = 1080/1.25, width = 1920/1.25)
frame.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

That is the code. My problem is that it doesn't want to format right. The two buttons, the 'x' and the '-', are supposed to be touching. Can someone help?

Comment: Put the buttons in a frame and use `.pack(side="right", anchor="n")` instead of `.grid`. Also you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194808/11106801) out

Comment: If I do that, then it won't stack in the way I want.

Comment: You have two widgets in column 1 of your grid: a Button that's fairly small, and a Frame that you've explicitly made rather big.  The widest width sets the width of the column - and in the absence of a `sticky=` option, all of the narrower items get centered in the column.  I can't tell you how to fix this, because I have no idea where you wanted the Frame to be located relative to the buttons.

Comment: It's going to be  hard to answer without a bit more detail. Do you expect the buttons to be to the far left? Should there be a blank space under the left-most button?

Comment: you could add image with expected result.

Comment: Can you please a bit more detail about your question for more clarity? You can add more details like what you are actually trying to make and what your code is about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *


color1 = "#031629"
color2 = "#1C1C1C"

root = Tk()
root.title("Everything BASE 1.0.0")
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(bg=color1)

def minim():
    # I usually use `root.iconify()`
    root.iconify()
    # root.wm_state("iconic")


buttons_frame = Frame(root, bg=color2)
buttons_frame.pack(fill="x")

exit_button = Button(buttons_frame, bg=color1, fg="white", text=" X ", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack(side="right", anchor="n")
min_button = Button(buttons_frame, bg=color1, fg="white", text=" - ", command=minim)
min_button.pack(side="right", anchor="n")

frame = Frame(root, bg=color2, height=1080/1.25, width=1920/1.25)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

In cases like this, it is better to use the [`.pack`](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) manager instead of `.grid`.

I just created a frame for the buttons. I used `.pack` for the widgets inside both `root` and `buttons_frame`. For this case `.pack` is much easier to use.

Comment: Why do you think `pack` is better? You should probably  explain that position because it's not obvious, since the OP's specific problem can easily be solved with `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `sticky='w'` in

```
min_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
```

then it will move it to the left - `west` - like this

[image]

---

Minimal working code with other changes

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def minim():
    root.wm_state("iconic")

# --- main ---

color1 = '#031629'
color2 = '#1C1C1C'

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Everything BASE 1.0.0')
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.configure(bg=color1)  # PEP8: `=` without spaces

exit_button = tk.Button(root, bg=color1, fg='White', text=" X ", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')

min_button = tk.Button(root, bg=color1, fg='White', text=' - ', command=minim)
min_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=color2, height=1080/1.25, width=1920/1.25)
frame.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want without left margin - like that

[image]

Then you could group buttons in `Frame` and put it in one cell in first row.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def minim():
    root.wm_state("iconic")

# --- main ---

color1 = '#031629'
color2 = '#1C1C1C'

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Everything BASE 1.0.0')
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.configure(bg=color1)  # PEP8: `=` without spaces

frame_titlebar = tk.Frame(root, bg=color1)
frame_titlebar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we') 

exit_button = tk.Button(frame_titlebar, bg=color1, fg='White', text=" X ", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

min_button = tk.Button(frame_titlebar, bg=color1, fg='White', text=' - ', command=minim)
min_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

title_label = tk.Label(frame_titlebar, text='Everything BASE 1.0.0', bg='red', fg='white')
title_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='wens')
frame_titlebar.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)  # use all free space

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=color2, height=1080/1.25, width=1920/1.25)
frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

It may be also useful to assign some functions/events to top bar - ie. to drag window.