# Has a tkinter window been resized by user

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How can I test if a tkinter window has been resized by the user?

Hopefully without binding the `<Configure>` event and implementing my own logic.

Most apps will never need this. But in some rare cases I may decide to display certain information or messages differently or not display them at all if I detect that the user has resized the window. It is difficult to come up with a contrived example that makes sense.

The reason I thought this may be possible is because on user resize `Tk` stops dynamic window sizing, which means that it remembers the resize event internally in some form. Whether this can be made available to the application is another story.

Comment: You're out of luck — binding to events is how it's done.

Comment: try using (window).winfo_height or (window).winfo_width methods.

Comment: What's wrong with binding to `<Configure>`? What problem are you trying to solve that requires you know when the user resizes the window? Maybe there are other ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I was just wondering if tkinter already had a built in method to check specifically if a window has been resized by user. As I understand it, the `<Configure>` event can be triggered by a few other conditions, so I would need to implement some logic. And I do not have to know about the resize right away.

Comment: @mcu I don't think there is an event specifically for the widget being resized. You best bet is to use `"<Configure>"`.

Comment: Answers using `<Configure>` are welcome too. But I think they should determine if the event was caused by user dragging the window border or something else.

Comment: @mcu Just save the current width and height of the widget in a variable and check if the new width is different using: `event.width`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: What if the width has changed for other reasons, such as the child widgets' sizes have changed?

Comment: @mcu Can you please show us a minimal version of your code? It really shouldn't matter if the user resized the window or another widget resized the window.

Comment: @TheLizzard: It would matter for the purposes of determining if the user has resized the window.

Comment: @mcu I am yet to encounter a situation where it is necessary to determine if the user resized the window. That is why I wanted to see your code. In most cases it wouldn't matter. You can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194808/11106801). With slight modifications it should be easy to generate an event when the user resizes that window.