# How to add elevation to root window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried searching for a way to add elevation to my Tkinter window but was unable to do so. I have removed the title bar from my window (and hence it is a custom one). Is there any direct/in-direct way to increase the elevation of the window/add some shadow effect for the same? (Basically the background color of the frame seems to get merged with the actual background on the screen)

**Program Code:**

```
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, master, filename):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        seq =  []
        try:
            while 1:
                seq.append(im.copy())
                im.seek(len(seq))# skip to next frame
        except EOFError:
            pass # we're done

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except KeyError:
            self.delay = 100

        first = seq[0].convert('RGBA')
        self.frames = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(first)]

        Label.__init__(self, master, image=self.frames[0])
        self.config(borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

        temp = seq[0]
        for image in seq[1:]:
            temp.paste(image)
            frame = temp.convert('RGBA')
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame))

        self.idx = 0

        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)

    def play(self):
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.idx])
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx == len(self.frames):
            self.idx = 0
        self.cancel = self.after(self.delay, self.play)        


root=Tk(relief='raised')
root.overrideredirect(True) # turns off title bar, geometry

# make a frame for the title bar
title_bar = Frame(root, bg='#181818', bd=2, highlightthickness=0)

# put a close button on the title bar
close_button = Button(title_bar, text=' X ', command=root.destroy, bg="#181818", padx=2, pady=2, activebackground='red', bd=0, font="bold", fg='white', highlightthickness=0)

# a canvas for the main area of the window
window = Canvas(root, bg='#181818', highlightthickness=0)

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
xwin=None
ywin=None
# bind title bar motion to the move window function

def move_window(event):
    root.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root, event.y_root))
def change_on_hovering(event):
    global close_button
    close_button['bg']='red'
def return_to_normalstate(event):
    global close_button
    close_button['bg']='#2e2e2e'


title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
close_button.bind('<Enter>',change_on_hovering)
close_button.bind('<Leave>',return_to_normalstate)

anim = MyLabel(window, 'test.gif')
anim.pack()

root.mainloop()

def stop_it():
    anim.after_cancel(anim.cancel)

root.mainloop()
```

**test.gif**

[image: test.gif]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

As we can see here in the output, there is barely any distinction between the background and the window as it would have been without `root.overrideredirect(True)`.

I am referring to this shadow/elevation that you can see beside the window in the below image (the background is basically the rest of the screen).

[image]

Comment: what do You mean by the _actual background_ and by _elevation_?

Comment: Hey, I have updated the answer with the required details (at the end).

Comment: @Matiiss Hey, do you think this is possible in Tkinter?

Comment: I have no idea, search online or wait for someone else to come by and answer this, I just don't know about this specific thing

Comment: @ShyamSingh You can put all of your widgets in a frame with a grey border. I did that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194808/11106801) and it doesn't look bad. I will upvote this question and wait for answer :D

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for that valuable comment! I'll get back to this as soon as I complete the rest of the project. Extremely sorry for the delay.