# how to disable a second window?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm just trying to create a window with a shadow. I want to move both windows at the same time. so far it works. however, when i click on the edge, the "shadow" window comes to the fore. is there a possibility to leave the second window permanently in the background?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class CFrame(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, bg="#1b1e21", bd=1, bdcolor="lime"):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.bg = bg
        self.bd = bd
        self.bdcolor = bdcolor

        self.title("CFrame")
        self.geometry("740x740+200+200")
        self.overrideredirect(1)

        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.dragWindow)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.clickWindow)

        self.shadow = Shadow()

        self.headingFrame = Frame(self, bg="lime")
        self.headingFrame.pack(fill="x")

        self.mainFrame = Frame(self, bg=self.bg, highlightthickness=bd,
                               highlightbackground=self.bdcolor, highlightcolor=self.bdcolor)
        self.mainFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

        self.exitButton = ttk.Button(self.headingFrame, text="\u2613", command=self.programQuit)
        self.exitButton.pack(side="right")

        self.offSetX = 0
        self.offSetY = 0

    def dragWindow(self, event):
        x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.offSetX
        y = self.winfo_pointery() - self.offSetY
        x2 = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.offSetX - 10
        y2 = self.winfo_pointery() - self.offSetY - 10
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x,y))
        self.shadow.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x2,y2))

    def clickWindow(self, event):
        self.offSetX = event.widget.winfo_rootx() - self.winfo_rootx() + event.x
        self.offSetY = event.widget.winfo_rooty() - self.winfo_rooty() + event.y

    def programQuit(self):
        ex = messagebox.askyesno("Quit?", "Quit?")
        if ex == 1:
            self.destroy()


class Shadow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Shadow")
        self.geometry("760x760+190+190")
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.attributes("-alpha", 0.3)

        self.bg = Frame(self, bg="black")
        self.bg.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cf = CFrame()

    cf.mainloop()
```

maybe a little bit too much code, but i think you can it imagn better with the whole example

Comment: Bind to `"<FocusIn>"` on your dummy window and use `.focus_force()` on the main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already did something like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194808/11106801). It works by binding to `"<FocusIn>"` on your dummy shadow window and calling `.focus_force()` on the main window. Like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class CFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, bg="#1b1e21", bd=1, bdcolor="lime"):
        super().__init__()

        self.bg = bg
        self.bd = bd
        self.bdcolor = bdcolor

        super().geometry("740x740+200+200")
        super().overrideredirect(True)

        super().bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag_window)
        super().bind("<Button-1>", self.click_window)

        self.shadow = Shadow()

        self.heading_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="lime")
        self.heading_frame.pack(fill="x")

        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=self.bg, highlightthickness=bd,
                                   highlightbackground=self.bdcolor,
                                   highlightcolor=self.bdcolor)
        self.main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

        self.exit_button = ttk.Button(self.heading_frame, text="\u2613",
                                      command=self.program_quit)
        self.exit_button.pack(side="right")

        self.offset_x = 0
        self.offset_y = 0

        self.shadow.bind("<FocusIn>", self.focus_main)

    def focus_main(self, event):
        super().focus_force()

    def drag_window(self, event):
        x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.offset_x
        y = self.winfo_pointery() - self.offset_y
        x2 = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.offset_x - 10
        y2 = self.winfo_pointery() - self.offset_y - 10
        super().geometry("+%d+%d" % (x,y))
        self.shadow.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x2,y2))

    def click_window(self, event):
        self.offset_x = event.widget.winfo_rootx() - self.winfo_rootx() + event.x
        self.offset_y = event.widget.winfo_rooty() - self.winfo_rooty() + event.y

    def program_quit(self):
        result = messagebox.askyesno("Quit?", "Are you sure you want to quit?")
        if result:
            super().destroy()
            self.shadow.destroy()


class Shadow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super().geometry("760x760+190+190")
        super().overrideredirect(True)
        super().attributes("-alpha", 0.3)
        super().config(bg="black")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cf = CFrame()
    cf.mainloop()
```

Also I removed the frame from the shadow window and replaced it with `<tkinter.Tk>.config(bg="black")`.

Another thing: Is there a point to calling `.title(...)` when you are going to use `.overrideredirect(True)`?

Comment: no, that was at first when im trying to make two windows. to see witch is first at foreground. but anyway, you are using ` super` is that important for that reason?

Comment: @JoeMo Nope, it's just to point out that I haven't defined that function myself but instead I am using the one from the `Tk` class.

Comment: @JoeMo Also I think you forgot `self.shadow.destroy()` in your `program_quit` method :D.

Comment: thanks. this `"<FocusIn>"` works. Yes I forget to drestroy it. hehe.thanks for this suggestion too