# Tkinter change "x"/window close Button icon

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

is there a way in python/tkinter to change the icon of the "x" so the window close button on the right top?
Like Firefox, they changed it too or resized it.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't support that but you can build your own custom window by telling `tkinter` to remove the titlebar and adding your own one. I did that a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66194808/11106801)

Comment: @TheLizzard, that is a great answer!