# Resize Frame With its widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to `tkinter`. I found a code which helps to resize the frames. However, when I add `ttk.treeview` to the frame, the frame starts showing a weird behaviour. If I have missed something obvious, please be gentle.

The site where I found the code: [Python Tk inter - Using bind to resize frame dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767062/python-tk-inter-using-bind-to-resize-frame-dynamically)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from math import *
HORIZONTAL = 1
VERTICAL   = 2

class App:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.Frame1 = Frame(top, bd=5, relief='raised', width=100)
        self.Frame1.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
        self.Frame2=Frame(top, bd=5, relief='raised', height=50)
        self.Frame2.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
        Label(self.Frame2,text="Sample App",font=("arial",18)).pack()
        self.treeview=ttk.Treeview(self.Frame1,columns=("Column 1","Column 2"))
        self.treeview.heading("Column 1",text="Column 1")
        self.treeview.heading("Column 2",text="Column 2")
        self.treeview.column("Column 1",width=70)
        self.treeview.column("Column 2",width=70)
        self.treeview.bind("<Button-1>",self.disable)
        self.treeview['show']="headings"
        self.treeview.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.Frame1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_resize)
        self.Frame1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_resize)
        self.Frame1.bind("<Motion>", self.resize_frame)
        self.resize_mode = 0
        self.cursor = ''
    def disable(self,event,*args):
        if self.treeview.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == "separator":
            return "break"

    def check_resize_mode(self, x, y):
        width, height = self.Frame1.cget('width'), self.Frame1.cget('height')
        mode = 0
        if x > width-10: mode |= HORIZONTAL    
        if y > height-10: mode |= VERTICAL
        return mode

    def start_resize(self, event):
        self.resize_mode = self.check_resize_mode(event.x, event.y)

    def resize_frame(self, event):
        if self.resize_mode:
            if self.resize_mode & HORIZONTAL:
                self.Frame1.config(width=event.x)
                width_col=floor(event.x/2)
                self.treeview.column("Column 1",width=width_col)
                self.treeview.column("Column 2",width=width_col)
        
                #self.dk.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        
            if self.resize_mode & VERTICAL:
                self.Frame1.config(height=event.y)
        else:
            cursor = 'sizing' if self.check_resize_mode(event.x, event.y) else ''
            if cursor != self.cursor:
                self.Frame1.config(cursor=cursor)
                self.cursor = cursor

    def stop_resize(self, event):
        self.resize_mode = 0

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+400+50")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you describe the weird behaviour? What is the intended outcome what is the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used `pack()` on `self.treeview`.  Changing column widths does not resize `self.treeview`, so it will shrink the frame to fit its size.

Try changing `self.treeview.pack(...)` to `self.treeview.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)` and remove the code of resizing the column widths of `self.treeview` (resize the frame will resize `self.treeview` which in turns resize the columns) as well:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from math import *
HORIZONTAL = 1
VERTICAL   = 2

class App:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.Frame1 = Frame(top, bd=5, relief='raised', width=200) # use larger width
        self.Frame1.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
        self.Frame2=Frame(top, bd=5, relief='raised', height=50)
        self.Frame2.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
        Label(self.Frame2,text="Sample App",font=("arial",18)).pack()
        self.treeview=ttk.Treeview(self.Frame1,columns=("Column 1","Column 2"))
        self.treeview.heading("Column 1",text="Column 1")
        self.treeview.heading("Column 2",text="Column 2")
        self.treeview.column("Column 1",width=70)
        self.treeview.column("Column 2",width=70)
        self.treeview.bind("<Button-1>",self.disable)
        self.treeview['show']="headings"
        #self.treeview.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.treeview.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.Frame1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_resize)
        self.Frame1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_resize)
        self.Frame1.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.resize_frame)
        self.resize_mode = 0
        self.cursor = ''

    def disable(self,event,*args):
        if self.treeview.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == "separator":
            return "break"

    def check_resize_mode(self, x, y):
        width, height = self.Frame1.cget('width'), self.Frame1.cget('height')
        mode = 0
        if x > width-10: mode |= HORIZONTAL    
        if y > height-10: mode |= VERTICAL
        return mode

    def start_resize(self, event):
        self.resize_mode = self.check_resize_mode(event.x, event.y)

    def resize_frame(self, event):
        if self.resize_mode:
            if self.resize_mode & HORIZONTAL:
                self.Frame1.config(width=event.x)
                """
                width_col=floor(event.x/2)
                self.treeview.column("Column 1",width=width_col)
                self.treeview.column("Column 2",width=width_col)
                """
                #self.dk.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        
            if self.resize_mode & VERTICAL:
                self.Frame1.config(height=event.y)
        else:
            cursor = 'sizing' if self.check_resize_mode(event.x, event.y) else ''
            if cursor != self.cursor:
                self.Frame1.config(cursor=cursor)
                self.cursor = cursor

    def stop_resize(self, event):
        self.resize_mode = 0

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+400+50")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Note that for your case, using `PanedWindow` is better:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.paned = tk.PanedWindow(top, sashwidth=4, sashrelief=tk.SUNKEN)
        self.paned.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.paned, bd=5, relief=tk.RAISED)
        columns = ("Column 1", "Column 2")
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.frame1, columns=columns, show="headings")
        self.treeview.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        for col in columns:
            self.treeview.heading(col, text=col)
            self.treeview.column(col, width=70)

        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.paned, bd=0)
        tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Simple App", font="Arial 18", bd=5, relief=tk.RAISED).pack(fill=tk.X)

        self.paned.add(self.frame1)
        self.paned.add(self.frame2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+400+50")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.