# Trying to resize the frame

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I was trying to add a files view in my text editor. Is there any way to resize `tkinter` frame by either x-axis or y-axis?

example:

[image]

like this resizing the files view.

Is there any way to do the same in a `tkinter` frame?

Comment: You can use paned window

Comment: Does this answer the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767062/python-tk-inter-using-bind-to-resize-frame-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, you want a splitter widget, you can make use of `PanedWindow`.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

splitter = tk.PanedWindow(root, handlesize=2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
splitter.pack(fill='both', expand=True)


leftFrame = tk.Frame(splitter, bg='red')
rightFrame = tk.Frame(splitter, bg='blue')

splitter.add(leftFrame, width=100)
splitter.add(rightFrame)


root.mainloop()
```

you can now expand the frame by using the handle.